# HTML form with JS does not work properly in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form with JS where I hide and show form's fields after choosing option with radiobuttons.

```
<?php require_once 'resources/menus/adminMenu.php'; ?>
<div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6 ">
    <div class="well bs-component">
        <form class="form-group" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Wyszukaj</legend>
                <div class="form-group" style="display: block" id="queryIndex">
                    <label for="index" class="control-label">Indeks</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="index" name="index" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="display: none" id="queryName">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Imię</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text">
                    <label for="surname" class="control-label">Nazwisko</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="surname" name="surname" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="display: none" id="queryFaculty">
                    <label for="faculty" class="control-label">Wydział</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="faculty" name="faculty" required="required">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Wydział A">Wydział A</option>
                        <option value="Wydział B">Wydział B</option>
                        <option value="Wydział C">Wydział C</option>
                        <option value="Wydział D">Wydział D</option>
                        <option value="Wydział E">Wydział E</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="display: none" id="querySubject">
                    <label for="subject" class="control-label">Kierunek</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" required="required">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Kierunek AA">Kierunek AA</option>
                        <option value="Kierunek AB">Kierunek AB</option>
                        <option value="Kierunek AC">Kierunek AC</option>
                        <option value="Kierunek BA">Kierunek BA</option>
                        <option value="Kierunek BB">Kierunek BB</option>
                        <option value="Kierunek BC">Kierunek BC</option>
                        <option value="Kierunek CA">Kierunek CA</option>
                        <option value="Kierunek CB">Kierunek CB</option>
                        <option value="Kierunek CC">Kierunek CC</option>
                        <option value="Kierunek DA">Kierunek DA</option>
                        <option value="Kierunek DB">Kierunek DB</option>
                        <option value="Kierunek DC">Kierunek DC</option>
                        <option value="Kierunek EA">Kierunek EA</option>
                        <option value="Kierunek EB">Kierunek EB</option>
                        <option value="Kierunek EC">Kierunek EC</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="display: none" id="querySystem">
                    <label for="system" class="control-label">System</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="system" name="system" required="required">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="st">Stacjonarne</option>
                        <option value="nst">Niestacjonarne</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="display: none" id="queryDegree">
                    <label for="degree" class="control-label">Stopień</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="degree" name="degree" required="required">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="I">1. stopień (inżynierskie/licencjat)</option>
                        <option value="II">2. stopień (magisterskie)</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="display: none" id="querySemester">
                    <label for="semester" class="control-label">Semestr</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="semester" name="semester" required="required">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="radio" name="search" value="index" checked="checked"
                           onClick="changeForm('queryIndex')"> Indeks
                    <input type="radio" name="search" value="name"
                           onClick="changeForm('queryName')"> Imię i nazwisko
                    <input type="radio" name="search" value="faculty"
                           onClick="changeForm('queryFaculty')"> Wydział
                    <input type="radio" name="search" value="subject"
                           onClick="changeForm('querySubject')"> Kierunek
                    <input type="radio" name="search" value="system"
                           onClick="changeForm('querySystem')"> System
                    <input type="radio" name="search" value="degree"
                           onClick="changeForm('queryDegree')"> Stopień
                    <input type="radio" name="search" value="semester"
                           onClick="changeForm('querySemester')"> Semestr
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function changeForm(element) {
                        document.getElementById('queryIndex').style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById('queryName').style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById('queryFaculty').style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById('querySubject').style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById('querySystem').style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById('queryDegree').style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById('querySemester').style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById(element).style.display = 'block';
                    }
                </script>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                    <div class="control-label">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="searchStudent">Szukaj
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also I have PHP file, where I get data from this form.

```
 function studentWindow()
    {
        $this->setView("AdminPanel", "StudentWindow");
        if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'searchStudent') {
            $query="";
            $data=array();
            if($_POST['search']=='index'){
                $data['index']=sanitizeString($_POST['index']);
                $query="st_index LIKE '?%'";
            }
            elseif($_POST['search']=='name'){
                $data['name']=sanitizeString($_POST['name']);
                $data['surname']=sanitizeString($_POST['surname']);
                $query="name LIKE '?%' AND surname LIKE '?%'";
            }
            elseif($_POST['search']=='faculty'){
                $data['faculty']=$_POST['faculty'];
                $query='AS st INNER JOIN subject AS s ON st.id_subject=s.id_subject INNER JOIN faculty AS f ON s.id_faculty=f.id_faculty WHERE f.name=?';
            }
            elseif($_POST['search']=='subject'){
                $data['subject']=$_POST['subject'];
                $query='AS st INNER JOIN subject AS s ON st.id_subject=s.id_subject WHERE s.name=?';
            }
            elseif($_POST['search']=='system'){
                $data['system']=$_POST['system'];
                $query='system=?';
            }
            elseif($_POST['search']=='degree'){
                $data['degree']=$_POST['degree'];
                $query='degree=?';
            }
            elseif($_POST['search']=='semester'){
                $data['semester']=$_POST['semester'];
                $query='semester=?';
            }
            $this->loadModel("AdminPanel");
            $model = new AdminPanelModel();
            $model->getStudents($query,$data);
        }
    }
```

This is a problem. I can't get data from forms and also the button doesn't work. I made other forms like this but without JS. This may be the cause. Do you have any suggestions or solutions?

P.S. Sorry for my English ;)

Comment: You need to start debugging yourself: what values are actually transferred from client to server? What SQL query is actually constructed on the server? What data is transferred back?

Comment: PS: switch statements are nice.

Comment: @Avenar In others forms button works properly

Comment: In that case never mind that comment. You should do as arkascha says and check which data your php actually receives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is using `required='required'` when the form fields are not required.

The user can submit at any time and it is not evident that you must click each radio button in turn to fill out that portion, if that was the intention.

I ran your code as plain HTML and examined the POST data in the Chrome Dev Tools and it works fine if you fill out all fields with `required`...

You will get an error in `console` that says the following:

```
An invalid form control with name='faculty' is not focusable.
```

Chrome is trying to focus the field to add error messages, but you set `style.display = 'none'` so it can't.